# tfa.metrics.F1Score calculated wrong?

Tags: tensorflow

I train a Keras model from scratch for image classification and print the F1 score during training. I use the following metrics in the `metrics` property in `model.compile()`:

```py
METRICS = [
    tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
    tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
    tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
    tfa.metrics.F1Score(name='f1', num_classes=7)
]
```

When I check my logs I have a precision of `0.98956`, a recall of `0.9875` and a F1 score of `0.98113`. [According to the formula in the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score) the F1 score should be `0.9885`. Is the formula or my setup wrong?

Comment: If you use threshold = 0.5 and average = 'macro', does the F1 score change to the desirer/sought value?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The value is smaller than the desired one. Apparently, precision and recall [cannot be used with multi-class classification](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/issues/1753)?

Answer (score 0):

a little late but, I hope it still helps,

From my research, I saw that the F1 score metrics was removed in Kera 2.0 because the score is approximated batch-wise.
I think you face this problem even you used the Tensorflow Addon.

For more detail: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794#issuecomment-287641301

If you want the F1 score, you can compute it at the end of the epoch
I implemented like that:

```py
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              metrics=[
                tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(),
                tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
                tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
              ])

class MetricsF1(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        precision = logs['precision']
        recall = logs['recall']
        f1_score = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
        print("F1 SCORE TRAIN:", round(f1_score, 4))

        val_precision = logs['val_precision']
        val_recall = logs['val_recall']
        val_f1_score = 2 * (val_precision * val_recall) / (val_precision + val_recall)
        print("F1 SCORE VALIDATION:", round(val_f1_score, 4))

model.fit(train_dataset,
          epochs=10,
          callbacks=[
            MetricsF1()
          ],
          validation_data=val_dataset
)
```